# React native looping through array

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have array of colors that is being rendered with a flatlist. The flatlist data is coming from remote url. The colors are hardcoded in the app. The issue is that I am having is that the json data that is coming from api contain more rows of data than the colors I have in a array which result in only 5 items showing. Can someone help me with allowing the colors to repeat (make the index of colors repeat over and over)

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://reactnative.dev/movies.json')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({data: json.movies});
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => {
        this.setState({isLoading: false});
      });
  }

  render() {
    const Colors = ['#1abc9c', '#9b59b6', '#7b59f9'];

    const {data, isLoading} = this.state;

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, padding: 24}}>
        {isLoading ? (
          <ActivityIndicator />
        ) : (
          <FlatGrid
            itemDimension={130}
            data={data}
            style={styles.gridView}
            keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
            // staticDimension={300}
            // fixed
            spacing={10}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => (
              <View
                style={[
                  styles.itemContainer,
                  {backgroundColor: Colors[index]},
                ]}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.title}</Text>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>{item.releaseYear}</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        )}
      </SafeAreaView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a modulo: `{backgroundColor: Colors[index % Colors.length]}`

```js
  const Colors = ["#1abc9c", "#9b59b6", "#7b59f9"];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(Colors[i % Colors.length]);
  }
```